# CRM 2011-control.SetParameter keeps coming up as undefined

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a javascript function which retrieves the information of a lookup field on a custom entity form and filters a subgrid view on the same form. The lookup field is "new_region" and the subgrid field is "Open_Opportunities". I currently have the script running as am OnLoad event on the form. Whenever I try to run the form, I get the following message:

"To use this saved view, you must remove criteria and columns that refer to deleted or non-searchable items."

Here is my script:

```js
function updateSubGrid() {

var relatedOpportunities = document.getElementById('Open_Opportunities'); 

var lookupField = new Array;
 
lookupField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_region').getValue(); 

if(lookupField != null) {
var lookupid = lookupField[0].id; 
}
else {
return;
}


if (relatedOpportunities == null || relatedOpportunities.readyState !='complete' ){
setTimeout('updateSubGrid()', 4000); 
return;
} 


var fetchXml = "<fetch distinct = 'false' mapping = 'logical' output-format='xml-platform' version='1.0'>"+
                         "<entity name = 'opportunity'>"+
                         "<attribute name = 'name'/>"+
                         "<attribute name = 'customerid'/>"+
                         "<attribute name = 'cs_awarddate'/>"+
                         "<attribute name = 'cs_inforcast'/>"+
                         "<attribute name = 'cs_overallprobability'/>"+
                         "<attribute name = 'cs_opportunitystage'/>"+
                         "<attribute name = 'cs_marketid'/>"+
                         "<attribute name = 'cs_estimatedrevenuemillions'/>"+
                         "<attribute name = 'ownerid'/>"+
                         "<attribute name = 'opportunityid'/>"+
                         "<link-entity name = 'new_salesplan' from='new_region' to='cs_marketid' alias='aa' link-type='outer'>"+ 
                         "<filter type = 'and'>"+
                        "<filter type = 'and'>"+
                         "<filter type = 'and'>"+
                         "<condition attribute ='statecode' value='0' operator='eq'/>"+
                         "<condition attribute ='ownerid' operator='eq-userid'/>"+ 
                         "<condition attribute = 'cs_marketid' operator='eq' uitype='opportunity' value='"+ lookupid + "'/>"+
                         "</filter>"+
                         "</filter>"+
                         "</filter>"+
                         "</link-entity>"+
                         "</entity>"+ 
                         "</fetch>"; 


relatedOpportunities.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml); 
relatedOpportunities.control.refresh();


}​
```

After using the F12 debugger, I have found that the line:

relatedOpportunities.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml);

continuously returns as undefined. My fetchXml was built using advanced find, and when I checked my fetchXml variable, it definitely was not null or undefined. I also tried to run this as an OnSave event and I received the same message. Additionally, the error file gave the error message "Server was unable to process request." Does anyone know why this may be occurring?

(I am on the latest rollup update, by the way)

Comment: Are all attributes in the fetchXml currently part of your data model and are they all enabled for search operations? Second: remove duplicate filter elements.

Comment: I've checked every single attribute and they are all search available and do not have any field security. I've also removed duplicate filter elements(I've even tried to run the script using just one condition) and I'm still getting the same error.